# Merging two arrays using method call

Tags: java

I am a beginner in Java looking for some help to finish my assignment. Here you have the assignment text  :

*A Stack of integers is an abstract data type that allows the following operations:*

*1) memorize integers (input function)*

*2) print the memorized numbers in the insertion order (print method)*

*3) reverse the insertion order of the numbers (reverse method)*

*4) concatenate two stacks (concatenate method)*

*5) copy the content of the stack to an array (toarray)*

*Write a java class to implement the abstract data type of integers. The program should work with the main file.*

The first thing i did was create a class that contains the methods such as: **print, input, reverse, concatenate, copy, etc** to store the integers in an array, print them using the print method, reverse the insertion order. No problems here.

My problem comes when i want to concatenate two arrays of integers (input from the main) using a method in the class. Instead, the program outputs some numbers + the "java.lang.NullPointerException" error which i think i understand reason for.

Here you can see the stack class:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Repo {

    private static int SIZE;
    private int [] Repo ;
    private int [] Repo2;
    private int top;

    Repo () {
        Repo = new int [SIZE];
    }

    Repo (int l) {
        Repo = new int [l];
    }

    public void input (int in) {

        Repo[top] = in;
        top++;
    }

    public void stampa () { //print

        for(top = 0; top < Repo.length; top++ ) {
            if(Repo[top]!=0) {
                System.out.print(Repo[top] + " ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public void gira() { //Invert

        for(top=0; top < Repo.length/2; top++) {
            int reverse = Repo[top];
            Repo[top] = Repo[Repo.length -top -1];
            Repo[Repo.length -top -1] = reverse;    
        }
    }

    public void appendi(Repo s) { //Append

        int aLen = Repo.length;
        int bLen = Repo2.length;
        int[] result = new int[aLen + bLen];

        System.arraycopy(Repo, 0, result, 0, aLen);
        System.arraycopy(Repo2, 0, result, aLen, bLen);

    }

    public void toarray () {

        int [] Repo2 = Repo.clone();

    }
}
```

Here you have the main:

```
public class TestRepo {

    // gioca con i repositori di interi

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // il risultato deve essere:
        //
        // 42 43 44 45
        // 1 2 3 45 44 43 42

        Repo r = new Repo(10);
        // r potra' contenere un massimo di 10 elementi

        Repo s = new Repo(20);

        r.input(42);
        r.input(43);
        r.input(44);
        r.input(45);

        r.stampa();

        s.input (1);
        s.input (2);
        s.input (3);

        s.gira();
        r.appendi(s);
        r.gira();
        r.stampa();  
    }
}
```

As you can see in the main, the numbers were entered using two different references r.input() & s.input().

In order to get the desired output i used the clone method to create a copy of the first array, merge it with a second one and then print it.

The output should be:

```
42 43 44 45
1 2 3 45 44 43 42
```

The output i get is:

```
42 43 44 45

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
      at Repo.appendi(Repo.java:46)
      at TestRepo.main(TestRepo.java:32)
```

I think the cause of the error is that i am not indicating the right reference in the "append" method, but i am not sure. There might be other errors i may not be aware of in my code.

Any help will be appreciated

Thank you very much

Comment: You never call `toarray()`so `Repo2` doesn't get initalized.  And I would use Arrays.copyOf() instead of clone.

Comment: as @WJS pointed out, you never initialised Repo2 and there for it's value is null.
therefore: int bLen = Repo2.length; throws an exception.

Comment: And your argument from appendi(Repo s) is never used. For example like this:int aLen = s.length;  You could give your appendi function both arrays as arguments. Because the way it is right now there is no need for an argument.

Comment: I also noticed that you put values in `result` in `appendi()` but then you never use `result` anywhere I could see.  You should have a general print routine that simply prints out stack.  When you append one stack to another, you need to create a new instance of a stack and then populate that stack from the other two. No need to clone anything or copy anything except one stack to another two stacks to another.

Answer (score 0):

As @WJS pointed out, you never initialised Repo2 and there for it's value is null.
therefore: int bLen = Repo2.length; throws an NullPointerException.
I think what you want to do is bLen = s.length as you probably want to size of this Repo plus the size of the repo you want to append, which is s, not Repo2.
This is only regarding your error.

I think your whole implementation is somewhat off.
I would advice you to do some reading on what exactly stacks are, just google it.
Now you work with arrays of integers, but I think you should use Stack instead. 
Why would you otherwise have a function called toArray, when your stack implemenation is already an array? Doesn't make sense. I could be wrong tough...
And for your print function I do not see why 0 should not be printed.

Nice job on the inverse though

Answer (score 0):

When performing your changes, you should work only with your stack implementation and nothing else.  Here are some pointers.

- Repo should only have one array which acts as a stack.
- Repo should have a method that prints itself and nothing else.
- Repo should be able to reverse itself. That can be done in place, but if you use another array it shouldn't be visible outside of your class.  If I were going to do this I would return a reversed version of the stack, rather than mutate one.
- The append method should take to stacks.  It should create an instance of the stack, populate that instance from the two passed stacks, and return it as a new instance of stack.
- A toArray method simply returns a copy of the array backing your stack. Don't just return the array object because mutating that array would also mutate the stack.

The above is how I might approach this. If I said anything that was in conflict with what your instructor wanted or expected, then your instructor's word certainly takes precedence.

---

Here is an example of how I would handle the `append` operation.  It works as follows:

- returns a new stack with the supplied stack appended to the calling stack.
- updates the index of the returned stack to point to the next slot.

For an existing `Stack one` and `Stack two` to append `two` to `one` would be called like this.

```
Stack appended = one.append(two);
```

Here is how it might be implemented (has not been thoroughly tested).

- `data` is the internal array that backs the stack
- `index` is the internal pointer that keeps track of elements.

```
    // append stack to this stack
    public Stack append(Stack stack) {
        // create a new stack to return
        Stack retStack = new Stack();

        // copy the data from the current stack to the new, ensuring 
        // space for both
        retStack.data = Arrays.copyOf(data, index + stack.index);
        System.arraycopy(stack.data, 0, retStack.data, index,
                stack.index);
        // update the returned stack's index.
        retStack.index = index + stack.index;

        // return the stack.
        return retStack;
    }
```

This is only one possibility. The overall idea is to return a `new stack` to house any modifications to an `existing stack` without changing the existing stack. It all depends on how much flexibility you are permitted with your solution and the requirements of your instructor.